# Programmatically set radio button state in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, radio-button

I have a simple problem that is driving me slightly nuts. I have a dialog-based MFC app which has 3 radio buttons on it, each with a click handler doing different things.

The third button activates a separate modal dialog, which has an `OnCancel` handler. The `OnCancel` handler calls `CheckRadioButton` on the parent dialog, to try to set the check to the first button in the group (thus indicating that the Modal dialog is no longer up). This does indeed set the check correctly, but for some reason it also generates a call to the third radio button click handler, and so the modal dialog reappears. This happens repeatedly (about 7 times), until eventually the repetitive calls stop, the modal dialog disappears, and all is apparently normmal.

This first became apparent in a large desktop app that I am adding features to, but it also occurs in a simple minimal dialog-based app, which I put together to test things.

I've tried this all sorts of ways, including using `CButton::SetCheck`, and also having a control variable and using `UpdateData(FALSE)`. All generate the same problem.

I'm probably doing something daft, but I can't see what it is!!
I'm using Visual Studio 2013. Any help greatly appreciated.

---

```
// in parent dialog
void Ctest_radioDlg::OnBnClickedRadio3()
{
    TRACE(_T("Clicked 3"));
    CTestDlg testDlg;
    testDlg.m_pParent = this;
    testDlg.DoModal();
}

// in modal dialog
void CTestDlg::OnCancel()
{
    m_pParent->CheckRadioButton(IDC_RADIO1, IDC_RADIO3, IDC_RADIO1);
    CDialogEx::OnCancel();
}
```

Comment: You can simplify this, change `OnBnClickedRadio3` to call `if (IDCANCEL==testDlg.DoModal()) CheckRadioButton(...)` This way `CTestDlg` is removed as suspect. You should perhaps show the message map, otherwise there shouldn't be any problem from what is shown here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately (and I didn't make this clear), the problem actually arose in a much larger and more complex program, in which the subsidiary dialog is non-modal. The code I posted is my attempt to narrow things down to produce the simplest example of the problem. In reality, I really do need to feed the information back from the (non-modal) dialog to its parent, indicating that the user has shut down the non-modal dialog, and the parent has to change its button state in response. I tried posting a message, but that was no better than calling the parent directly.

Answer (score 1):

I would utilize MFC's DDX/DDV mechanism auto-handle the radio button behavior (otherwise, you end up having to do work-arounds for your own radio-button behavior).

Add a radio button control data member, m_iRadio (0 based radio button group enum).  Then in your CheckRadioButton(), just set m_iRadio to the 0-based value instead of the control ID

enum {RADIO_OPTION1, RADIO_OPTOIN2, RADIO_OPTION3};

```
Ctest_radioDlg::CheckRadioButton(int eRadioOption)
{
  m_iRadio = eRadioOption;
  UpdateData(false);  // MFC magic occurs here
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but that was actually my starting code that revealed the problem. I've been trying to pair things down to the minimal to narrow the possible sources of the problem.

Comment: @BillHeitler Was your equivalent of the m_iRadio value always correct?  If not, then it could have just been an issue with your resource definition.  (see next comment, this one is too long).

Comment: Radio button groups must be configured correctly, that is the first radio button in the group must be identified as a beginning of a GROUP in the resource definition.  Then, a control AFTER the last radio button  (or wrapped around back to the beginning if at the end of the control list) must have a GROUP setting also to "end" the radio-button group.  If that is missing, or there are other "buttons" before the "next" group, you will get bad behavior with your DDX/DDV code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check a radiobutton with id IDC_RADIO1.
m_Radio is the controlvariable of radiobutton group.

```
m_Radio.GetParent()->CheckRadioButton(IDC_RADIO1, IDC_RADIO2, IDC_RADIO1);
```